# Spacing around a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I am trying to set all spacings around and within a `tabular` environment to be equivalent with standard paragraph text.

The table heading and the table should have no indentation. I placed comments where I would like to set the spacing. The table heading is too close to the table if in the heading text there is no letter extending below baseline (e.g. no g, j, p, q or y). Also the spacing between rows seems to be different than interline spacing.

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

Text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text.

{
    \setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
    Table head is too close:\\% <-- set space after the table heading equal to interline spacing
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
       Text text text text & Text text text text\\ % <-- set spacing between rows equal to interline spacing
       Text text text text & Text text text text\\
    \end{tabular}
} % <-- space after the table equal to interparagraph spacing

Text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text.

Text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

By default a `tabular` is vertically centred which means its height is a lot bigger than `\baselineskip` so TeX can not preserve baselineskip spacing after `too close:\\%` so will use `\lineskip` glue instead, and throw you off the baseline grid. If you use `\begin{tabular}[t]` then alignment will be based on the baseline of the first row of the table which gives you a better chance of preserving baseline spacing.

Note  `\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}` in your document works but most paragraph settings at that point have no effect as the containing group is closed before the paragraph ends. It would be clearer to have a blank line before the `}`